# Passing messages to a DLL's entry point

Tags: delphi, dll, delphi-xe

I have a DLL which exectues some code at its entry point, i.e.

```
procedure MainDLL(Reason: Integer);
begin
  { ... Code here ... }
end;

begin
  DLLProc := @MainDLL;
end.
```

Now, I would like to pass some values to the DLL's entry point from an external application. I have tried creating a hidden window inside the DLL, like that:

```
const
  WM_JAJCO = WM_USER + 1024;

type
  TWnd = class(TObject)
    class procedure DLLWndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
  end;

{ ... }

class procedure TWnd.DLLWndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
var
  Tmp: DWORD;
begin
  if (Msg.Msg = WM_JAJCO) then
  begin
    PNewHandle := Msg.LParam;
    CreateThread(nil, 0, @Starter, nil, 0, Tmp);

    Msg.Result := 0;
  end else
    Msg.Result := DefWindowProc(MyHnd, Msg.Msg, Msg.WParam, Msg.LParam);
end;

// in the entry point
MyHnd := AllocateHWND(TWnd.DLLWndProc);
```

Then, after I initialize the DLL in the caller application, I use:

```
SendMessage(FindWindow('TPUtilWindow', nil), WM_USER + 1024, 0, wi.WndHandle);
Application.ProcessMessages();
```

But the window created inside the DLL does not seem to receive the message. Do you happen to know why?

If that's a bad method and you have a different solution, please let me know.

Comment: Why don't you export a function off your DLL and pass the arguments to this exported function via `GetModuleHandle`, `GetProcAddress` and a call on the obtained pointer?

Comment: But the entry point is executed once I called `LoadLibrary`, no? I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that the injected DLL really does create your window handle. WinSight or Spy++ should help you there. Once you know the window really does exist make sure FindWindow find your window handle and not another one with the same class name. IIRC, even the Delphi IDE itself creates window handles using this class name.

Comment: You're right, but the problem lies somewhere else. Please check my newest comment to David Heffernan's answer.

Answer (score 2):

That's a rather tortuous approach. You are supposed to do as little as possible in the DllMain function. The canonical solution is to create a dedicated function to perform initialization. Arrange for the host app to call the initialization function before calling anything else.

The most likely reason your version fails is that there are a lot of windows with that class name. Every window created by AllocHwnd has that class name. FindWindow probably just finds the wrong one.

---

On the other hand, you mention in passing in a comment that this DLL is injected! In that case you can make your method work by using a unique class name or giving the window a unique title so that you can find it.

Finally the call to ProcessMessages looks to be gratuitous.

Comment: The thing is that the DLL is injected into another process, and I don't know how to call an exported function of that DLL once it is injected into the process.

Comment: The funny thing is that when I create the window in the DLL and send a message to it from the DLL, it receives it, but when I call FindWindow() from the injecting executable, it cannot find the window.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using DLLMain for this. Just export your own init function and call it manually.